# Does * match hyphens in a glob in bash?

Tags: bash, glob

Today I was looking for a file named cfg-local.properties in a directory and its subdirectories.

I used:

```
find . -iname *.properties
```

Output:

```
./gradle.properties
```

Then, I tried:

```
find . -iname *-*.properties
```

Output:

```
./cfg/src/test/resources/cfg-local.properties
./cfg/src/main/resources/cfg-local.properties
./cfg/build/classes/test/cfg-local.properties
./cfg/build/resources/test/cfg-local.properties
./cfg/build/resources/main/cfg-local.properties
```

Shouldn't the asterisk match any character, including hyphens, in a glob expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will match, however you are actually running the command:

```
find . -iname gradle.properties
```

Insted, run:

```
find . -iname '*.properties'
```

When you type and run `find . -iname *.properties` , the `*.properties` part will be expanded by the shell to match files. (a process called globbing).

In your second example, `find . -iname *-*.properties` ,the `*-*.properties` doesn't match any file, so no filename expansion is performed and `*-*.properties` is passed verbatim to the `find` command.

Enclosing a word inside single quotes, like '*.properties' will prevent the shell from performing globbing.